# Proof of Accommodation in England

Tags: uk, australian-citizens, visa-free-entry, proof-of-accommodation

Hey so I am Australian and am staying with a friend in London when I arrive for a 1 week holiday. Do I need any document for customs proving I have accommodation? Or do they even ask this question?

Only because when I came to Spain for the same reason, staying with a friend. They told me I had to have proof of Accommodation. Even if I was only here for 2 weeks.

Comment: You're from Australia. They are very unlikely to ask for proof. You can let your friend scrawl something on a piece of paper to that effect and email to you. Or just have the friends phone handy.

Comment: You haven't said where you actually live, but if you live in Australia then they *might* be suspicious about a trip halfway around the world for only a week. Their reaction to that depends how you present yourself I suspect.

Answer (score 2):

If you check out the Visitor entry requirements here https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y you get advice to bring the same documents with you that you’d use to apply for a visa, to show to officers at Immigration. It would be a good idea to have some evidence of where you’ll stay in case you are asked eg an email invite from your friend, with their address and contact number.